# How to configure the Orage Calendar & Clock

Tags: calendar

Is there a way to change the first day of the week into Ubuntu Studio 15.10 (Orage calendar & clock)?

I'm in Chile, but the first day of any week is Sunday. However, at my calendar, the first week day is Monday.

How could I change it? ???

Greetings & Blessings from Chile!!!

Juan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the first weekday to Sunday you need to change the `locale` file, recompile the `locale` definition files and restart the unity panel. `first_weekday 1` is Sunday. `2` is Monday...

```
sudo sed 's/first_weekday .*/first_weekday 1/' -i /usr/share/i18n/locales/${LANG%.UTF-8}
sudo locale-gen
killall unity-panel-service
```